# Time period over days

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
'Time_order': ['2019-01-01 07:00:00', '2019-01-01 07:25:00', '2019-01-02 07:02:00', '2019-01-02 07:27:00', '2019-01-02 06:58:00', '2019-01-03 07:24:00', '2019-01-04 07:03:00', '2019-01-04 07:24:00', '2019-01-05 07:05:00', '2019-01-05 07:30:00', '2019-01-06 07:00:00', '2019-01-06 07:25:00', '2019-01-07 07:02:00', '2019-01-07 07:27:00', '2019-01-08 06:58:00', '2019-01-08 07:24:00', '2019-01-09 07:03:00', '2019-01-09 07:24:00', '2019-01-10 07:05:00', '2019-01-10 07:30:00',
'2019-01-11 017:00:00', '2019-01-11 17:25:00', '2019-01-12 07:02:00', '2019-01-12 07:27:00', '2019-01-13 06:58:00', '2019-01-13 07:24:00', '2019-01-14 07:03:00', '2019-01-14 07:24:00', '2019-01-15 07:05:00', '2019-01-15 07:30:00']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Time_order'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time_order'])
df['hour'] = df['Time_order'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S)
```

I wanted to make a `time_period = 25 minutes` of length 25 minutes, so that I can check wether there are orders in that time_period. For example: I will start checking everyday starting from midnight, e.g. from `00:00:00` to  `00:25:00` and claculate how many orders are in that order and then move on by a 5 minutes, e.g. from `00:05:00` to `00:30:00` and so on scanning the whole day until `23:59:00`. What I am expecting is how many orders where made and pick the maximum ones, so that it returns at which time there is a peak of orders during that time period.

I tired the following:

```
x = 12 * 24 # each five minutes per hour (12) times 24 hours (a day)
for i in range(x):
    df[f'each{i}_minutes_start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time_order']).dt.floor(f'{i}_min')
    df[f'each{i}_minutes_end'] = df[f'each{i}_minutes_start'] + pd.Timedelta(minutes = 5)

    df['time_period'] = df[f'each{i}_minutes_start'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:S%') + '-' + pd.to_datetime(df[f'each{i}_minutes_end']).dt.strtime('%H:%M:S%')
```

at this point I stucked and could not come forward. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this works:

`df.set_index('Time_order').resample("5min").count().rolling(6)['ID'].sum()`

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. It works but unfortunately not as expected, since it looks / runs in 5 minutes wise (this is actually correct). However, I am struggling now with moving in one minute wise, e.g. we start from ```00:00:00``` and scann all orders in here till ```00:25:00``` and then move forward to ```00:01:00``` till ```00:26:00``` and  ```00:02:00``` till ```00:27:00``` and so on.